# Is it possible to post only the content page and keep master page as is?

Tags: asp.net-2.0, master-pages

I have one master page which applies to all pages in this website. On some of the button click or user events, I want that only content pages are posted back and all the controls of master page should not refresh.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need partial rendering which is provided by UpdatePanel. You can put your ContentPlaceHolder control onto an UpdatePanel in the master page. Another way is using IFrame.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/downloads/archive/